# How to re-paint a Gtk::Image component using glade and gtkmm c++

Tags: c++, gtk

I have a folder with many images, I've loaded the filenames into a vector of string and want to display the images in a GTK::Image component like a video, 25 frames (images) per second. But I the component don't re-draw after run the app.

I call the queue_draw(), but nothing change. How I do it?

EDIT:

The main function is like:

```
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.example");

refBuilder = Gtk::Builder::create();
try{
    refBuilder->add_from_file("main_window2.glade");
}
catch(const Glib::FileError& ex){
    std::cerr << "FileError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
catch(const Glib::MarkupError& ex){
    std::cerr << "MarkupError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
catch(const Gtk::BuilderError& ex){
    std::cerr << "BuilderError: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

refBuilder->get_widget("main_window", main_window);
cout << "window: " << main_window << endl;

if(main_window)
{

    Gtk::ImageMenuItem* newButton = nullptr;
    Gtk::ImageMenuItem* openButton = nullptr;
    Gtk::ImageMenuItem* saveButton = nullptr;
    Gtk::Button* playButton = nullptr;
    refBuilder->get_widget("new_button", newButton);
    refBuilder->get_widget("open_button", openButton);
    refBuilder->get_widget("save_button", saveButton);
    refBuilder->get_widget("play_button", playButton);
    refBuilder->get_widget("image_container", container);
    refBuilder->get_widget("image_component", image_component);


    if(playButton)
        playButton->signal_clicked().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(on_image_draw));
    if(newButton)
        newButton->signal_activate().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(on_new_button_activate) );
    if(openButton)
        openButton->signal_activate().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(on_open_button_activate) );
    if(saveButton)
        saveButton->signal_activate().connect( sigc::ptr_fun(on_save_button_activate) );

    cout << "running main window" << endl;
    app->run(*main_window);
}

delete main_window;
```

And when clicked in playButton, the drawing code is called

```
static void on_image_draw(){
    string path = video.getDirectory();
    string aux = path + "/";
    cout << "reproduzindo: " << aux << endl;
    vector<string> vetor = video.get_imageVector();
    cout << "vetor" << endl;
    for(auto frame: video.get_imageVector()){
        aux += frame;
        cout << "frame: " << aux << endl;

        image->clear();
        image->set(aux);
        Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> pix = image->get_pixbuf();
        pix = pix->scale_simple(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Gdk::INTERP_BILINEAR);
        image->set(pix);

        image->queue_draw();
        aux = path+"/";
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: ok, code added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to draw all your frames in the `draw` signal handler. You basically need to set the image, then call `queue_draw`. You're doing this right, but then you must let GTK+ do its part of the work. You can't just loop: calling `queue_draw` puts a `draw` event in the main loop that GTK+ needs to process to draw your image.

Remember you are single-threaded, so the CPU is like a shovel. When you are in a callback, you get the shovel and do your work. You can't expect GTK+ to process the events you send to it if you don't give it the shovel back.

Here's how you're supposed to architcture this stuff. Please keep in mind that if you need 25fps, this approach is sub-optimal, and you should probably give a look at video libraries like `gstreamer`.

So when you press play, you're supposed to trigger an event source like a timer or idle handler. That's because you need something to say: I need to isplay a new image. Give a look at `g_timeout_add` or `g_idle_add` in the GLib for that (I know only the names for the C api, find the equivalent ones in gtkmm).

Then in the callback associated to that timeout or idle event, you set your image (a single one, no loop), and that's all. Not sure calling `queue_draw` is even required. It would be if you were drawing by hand in a GtkDrawingArea, but as that's a GtkImage, so by setting a new image you say implicitely that the image has changed and should be redrawn.